# Providing an installer for asmx Webservices

Tags: iis, deployment, installation, asmx

What is the best way to deploy a couple of asmx webservices to IIS. (6.0, 6.1, 7.0)
The services are an optional install and I think the most convenient way to install them would be some kind of Windows Installer package.
I created a small C# program that directly modifies the IIS Metabase, but this only works on IIS 6.0 and 6.1 and I don't want to ship something that might harm a customers IIS installation.

Our services (~10 different .asmx files) are all precompiled and organized in the following structure:

```
 /services
   /serviceA
      /bin
      Service.asmx
   /serviceB
      /bin
      Service.asmx
   /serviceC
      /bin
      Service.asmx
      ...
      ..
      .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WiX](http://wix.sf.net/) is really best tool to do any kind of software deployment on the Windows platform. Among other things, it includes custom actions for this kind IIS configuring, see XML elements <iis:WebServiceExtension>, <iis:WebSite>, <iis:WebVirtualDir> and <iis:WebApplication> for details.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will look into that.
Do they provide Visual Studio support?

Comment: Yes. After installing WiX, you should see "WiX Project" in the new Visual Studio new project dialog.  However, the Visual Studio support at the moment is mostly just project build options and IntelliSense for editing the WiX XML files.

Answer (score 0):

I did this a long time back (XP) using VBScript and the VS installer?

Id imagine there is a much nicer way to do this now

Comment: I think one could use WMI with VBS to accomplish the task, but there must be some better options.